# PCI-Express Processor/Co-processor cards

Tags: cpu, pcie

I am hoping someone might be able to help:

In the days when I started with computing (C64 and later Amigas) expansion slot cards with co-processing ability were relatively common.  I am looking for any modern analogue to this as I would like to build a Multi-CPU and GPU system, therefore I am looking for any information on products similar to [this](http://www.ieiworld.com/product_groups/industrial/content.aspx?keyword=PICOe-b&gid=00001000010000000001&cid=08141333914287007902&id=0C090521963186388827) ([wayback machine page here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140327004825/http://www.ieiworld.com/product_groups/industrial/content.aspx?keyword=PICOe-b&gid=00001000010000000001&cid=08141333914287007902&id=0C090521963186388827)), preferably with an AMD CPU?

Any help/information greatly appreciated as I have searched online for quite some time with no real success.

Cheers in advance.

NB:  it looks like there may be an update from the original link, which leads to a product that may suit, if anyone else is interested: [this I7 PCI card](https://www.ieiworld.com/mustang-200/en/)

Comment: Using GPUs for general-purpose application acceleration is very common, and there are many software tools, both free and commercial, available to help you do this. But this question would be a better fit at [Superuser.SE](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: Thanks, didn' even think about superuser.se.  I use GPGPUs already, even from before the advent of opencl etc, and they are quite verssatile, but I now find a need for full fledged additional CPUs hence my question, will post on Superuser however:)  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

PCI express is really too slow for this. You need a motherboard designed to take multiple CPUs. These are available for up to 4 CPUs, although this is not cheap.

I believe the card you linked to is a "single board computer", so I'm not even sure it would work in a normal PC. It's probably designed for connection to a backplane or "mezzanine" system.

You can get "exotic" processors and FPGA add-in cards, e.g.:
http://www.nallatech.com/PCI-Express-FPGA-Cards/pcie-287n-7-series-fpga-network-processing-card.html

Comment: I have used similar cards in the past, still have a 286, 386 and 486 on seperate ISA/ZORRO cards for my Amigas, also have a 486 pci card (ancient and cant remember the make atm, will look it up when I get home) and they work wonderfully provided you either have custom software to utilise them with VMs or are happy to run a single tower cluster compute system:)  The card I linked fits in my home PC in a PCIe mini slot too.

Comment: Correction PCIe mini should have read PCIe x1

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using Intel [MIC](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/many-integrated-core/intel-many-integrated-core-architecture.html). Quite a few servers for math processing use it.

Comment: I like the idea of the Xeon PHI, however it is a full in-chip OS and hardware solutions, running uOS. Not so bad, but my primary aim is to make a PCIe expandable processing system, although I am looking into the PHI as and aside:)